# Django filtered and pagination issue

Tags: django, filter, pagination, django-queryset

I have a form that filter a queryset, filtering are ok, but if I use pagination links, I loose the filtering value. How can I paginate my filter result ?

template table.html

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="{{request.path}}?page=1">
                                    First
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="{{request.path}}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
                                    Previous
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for page_number in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                            {% if page_number <= page_obj.number|add:3 and page_number >= page_obj.number|add:-3 %}
                                {% if page_obj.number == page_number %}
                                    <li class="page-item active">
                                        <a class="page-link" href="{{request.path}}?page={{ page_number }}">
                                            {{ page_number }}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li class="page-item">
                                        <a class="page-link" href="{{request.path}}?page={{ page_number }}">
                                            {{ page_number }}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
class CmsView(ListView):
    queryset = Cmsexport.objects.all().values()
    model = Cmsexport
    template_name = 'table.html'
    context_object_name = 'table'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CmsView, self).get_queryset()
        field = self.request.GET.get('field')
        lookup = self.request.GET.get('lookup')
        value = self.request.GET.get('value')
        reset = self.request.GET.get('btn-reset')

        if (field and lookup and value) is not None:
            field = self.request.GET.getlist('field')
            lookup = self.request.GET.getlist('lookup')
            value = self.request.GET.getlist('value')

            query = dict()

            for (f,l,v) in zip(field,lookup,value):
                q = f.lower().replace(" ", "_") + '__' + l
                query[q] = v

            queryset = queryset.filter(**query).values()

        if reset:
            queryset = queryset.all().values()

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CmsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CmsFilterForm()

        return context
```

How get the filterset when paginate?

Please help me, thx :p

I have a form that filter a queryset, filtering are ok, but if I use pagination links, I loose the filtering value. How can I paginate my filter result ?

Comment: I would *strongly* advise against filtering on an arbitrary field. People could do queries like `author__password__gte='a'` to binary search over the (hopefully) hashed password, and thus obtain the (hashed) passwords, or other sensitive data you don't want to exploit, like `author__gender` or `author__address` for example. See: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/filter-on-arbitrary-input-like-request-get.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to pass the `request.GET` data to the next page, we can do this with:

```
<a class="page-link" href="{{request.path}}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}&amp;page={{ page_number }}">
```

but I would *strongly* advise against filtering on an *arbitrary* field. People could do queries like `author__password__gte='a'` to binary search over the (hopefully) hashed password, and thus obtain the (hashed) passwords, or other sensitive data you don't want to exploit, like `author__gender` or `author__address` for example. You should always list what fields should be able to filter, not just any field (except a list of forbidden ones). Even if for now there are no (related) fields with sensitive data, eventually in the future one might add such fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the table there are no sensitive data, like password, or personal info. The field are limited.

Comment: @RobinTheys: yes, but that is the entire point: one can follow relations. Like `ForeignKey`s, but also *reversed* `ForeignKey`s. This thus means that if there is one "path" from the table to a data with sensitive data, we have a problem. If you thus have a table like `product` for example, it could mean you have somethin like a `ForeignKey` to `department` that oversees it, and eventually a `manager`, so one can filter with `product__department__manager__password`.

Comment: @RobinTheys: and even if that is not the case *now*, it can be in the future, so that would mean that each time you introduce new (sorts) of data, it would mean you need to reevaluate it, eventually it is likely that you will fail to do this. A lot of security vulnerabilities originate from sloppiness over time when initially there is no issue at all, but eventually there is a way for hackers to "escalate" it to something sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I create a tag that keeps the other params in url, you can use it like this:

```
href="?{% url_replace request 'page' i %}"
```

this is the tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):
    dict_ = request.GET.copy()
    dict_[field] = value
    return dict_.urlencode()
```